# event of selecting a item in combobox

Tags: c#, events, combobox, textbox, visible

I have a combo box and textbox in form, (in windows form platform), the textbox visible is false by default, I want to show (visible=true) the the textbox when the specific item of combo box selected.

which event of combobox is suitable for this work!

Comment: [ComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged.aspx)? EDIT: Reading the MSDN, seems like [ComboBox.SelectionChangedCommited](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectionchangecommitted.aspx) might be better. But perhaps you ought to specify which platform you're using (WinForms, WPF, Silverlight, ASP.NET)

Comment: `Combobox.SelectionChanged` should do it.

Comment: If you want it to be triggered only if _the user_ selects something you should use `SelectionChangeCommitted`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you're depending on a fixed index in the combo box items use SelectedIndexChange event

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == yourindex)
        textBox1.Visible = true; 
    else
        textBox1.Visible = false; 
}
```

if you're depending on combo box selected item value use SelectedValueChanged event

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString() == "yourvalue")
        textBox1.Visible = true;
    else
        textBox1.Visible = false; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use the combobox [SelectedIndexChange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged.aspx) event or [Selecton Change Committed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectionchangecommitted.aspx)and in that event check for the **selectedvalue** of your combobox like

```
          if(combobox1.SelectedValue == desiredvalue)
               textBox1.Visible = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

This Code will definitely help you.

```
if (comboBox2.Text.ToString() == "Desired Value")
     comboBox1.Visible = true;
else
     comboBox1.Visible = false;
```